# First use of XSLT: page shows blank

Tags: html, xml, xslt, sitemap

I am trying my hand at XSLT using this page as a guide:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xsl.asp

I basically tried to modify the given XSL information to suit my tags, which happen to be in the form of a sitemap. However, when i apply the XSL style to my XML page, it shows as blank! Clearly i am missing/forgetting or not seeing something. Please help.

My XML (snippet only):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl" ?>
<!-- sitemap-generator-url="http://www.auditmypc.com/free-sitemap-generator.asp" -->
<!-- This sitemap was created using the free tool found here: http://www.auditmypc.com/free-sitemap-generator.asp -->
<!-- Audit My PC also offers free security tools to help keep you safe during internet travels -->
<urlset 
xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"
>
<url>
<loc>http://www.site.com/</loc>
<lastmod>2014-03-17T13:30:25-05:00</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://www.site.com/index.php?format=feed&#x26;type=rss</loc>
<lastmod>2014-03-17T13:28:20-05:00</lastmod>
</url>
</urlset>
```

My XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">

<xsl:for-each select="urlset/url">
<div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
<span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="loc"/></span>
</div>

<div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
<span>Last Modified:<xsl:value-of select="lastmod"/></span>
</div>
</xsl:for-each>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `urlset` element and its descendants in your example XML document are all in the `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9` namespace, so in order to match them with XPath expressions you must bind a prefix to that namespace and use it consistently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">

    <xsl:for-each select="sm:urlset/sm:url">
      <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
        <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="sm:loc"/></span>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
        <span>Last Modified:<xsl:value-of select="sm:lastmod"/></span>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </body>
</html>
```

In XSLT/XPath 1.0, unprefixed element names *always* mean elements in no namespace, and prefixed names take the namespace bindings from the *stylesheet*, not from the input XML.

As an aside, if you're writing XSLT to be interpreted on the client side by browsers then you will be restricted to XSLT 1.0, so I suggest you find a good 1.0-specific tutorial and reference guide.  The material on w3schools isn't always clear about what version of XSLT/XPath it refers to and you'll get frustrated if you keep trying things that don't work, only to find they're 2.0-only constructs...

Comment: This makes sense. Basically since i declared that name space in my XML file, i also need to reference it when speaking about nodes or there is no way to know what nodes i speak of. I tried this fix and it instantly worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remember, XPath (and therefore XSLT) is namespace-aware, but (in the 1.0 version of these standards at least) does not have the concept of default namespace (xmlns=) assignment. If you want to select namespaced nodes, your XPath must use explicit prefixes bound to the correct namespaces.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, i am new to XSL.... please help me to better understand how to access the data nodes if i use namespaces. May i do something like omit the xmlns from my xsl file and it should then work? I apologize but i literally did copy the example and tweak it a little, so i might not have the background info to make full sense of your answer.